# Unable to Connect remote MYSQL server

Tags: mysql

I have given all privileges to the `root` user, but I am unable to access remotely. I have given permission in firewall to access the port 3306 but I am unable to connect.

I am getting the error: `your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server xxx.xxx.x.xx:3306`

Comment: what is the error you are getting.?

Comment: you have to enable the external connection in mysql configuration. As per now it is only enabled inside your LAN. Please note that you should be very carefull opening the connection to wildcards

Comment: @AbdulWaheed......It is showing that "your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server xxx.xxx.x.xx:3306"

Comment: Are you able to connect database locally?

Comment: Is the root user 'root'@'%' or 'root'@'localhost'?

Comment: @KeertiSystematixInfotech.....yep

Comment: Hey @JimWright....Thank you for asking this question....previously it was 'root'@'localhost', i created a new user 'root1'@'%'. I am able to access now  :)

Comment: @Teja FYI you can do 'root'@'%' as well. I would advise not using root though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing up this answer as you said my comment was the answer you needed.

Your root user is probably `'root'@'localhost'` which means it will only accept logins from localhost. Create `'root'@'%'` to allow logins from anywhere.

I recommend not using `%` unless you really lock down the permissions. Even better though, use `'root'@'YOUR IP HERE'`!

Answer (score 0):

Look inside the my.cnf file for the bind address directive. This will tell mysql what IP to get access from.

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

**0.0.0.0 is there only to provide the most generic answer but for security reasons should be replaced by a specific address**
Please note that the safe way to do this is to specify only some specific IP and not use a wildcard for that. This way only trusted clients will be able to login.

**NOTE:**
check if you granted to the user that will connect the permission on that IP (or from wildcard). If not you have to run these:

```
GRANT ALL privileges ON testDB.* TO 'testUSER'@'IP_Address' IDENTIFIED BY 'testPassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Adapt these commands to your environment

Comment: Added this bind-address in my.ini and restarted the server.Same result unable to connect

Comment: what ip did you add? this is not the right one to use in your case. you need to use the public ip of the client that will login

Comment: Right now i have given 0.0.0.0, if it works i will change ip

Comment: 0.0.0.0 shouldn't be used at all! This is the most unsafe way to configure the server